# Rails. How to use a form builder object through javascript and Jquery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, nested-forms

I have been reading this forum for 3 days so I dare to ask my question :-)

I have a

```
<%= form_for(@post)  do |f| %> which builds a @post.
```

and

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
```

comments are enter via a complex mechanism (suggestion via a typehead) and when a user selects a comment in the typeahead list, it should call the add_comment(f, new_comment_text) which is in my posts_controller.

```
$.ajax({
        url : 'http://mywebsite/posts/add_comment',
        type : 'post', 
        data : 'new_comment_text='+datum.value, 
        dataType : 'html',
```

add_comment(f, new_comment_text) works with

```
new_object = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(:comments).klass.new
```

this would work with classical link_to or submit call.

But my problem is that I need to pass the f object through the AJAX call.

In fact, my nested comments will be saved simultaneously. So I need to handle with unsaved objects that have nested_attributes (number of comments can not by forecast).

My posts_controller is as follows:

```
def new
    @post = Post.new()
end 

def add_comment(f, new_comment_text)
    new_object = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(:comments).klass.new
    and much more...to render a partial of build comments...
end
```

**To sum up, I want:**

@post = Post.new() (in posts_controller - no problem)

Build a form_for(@post) do |f| (in my new view - no problem)

Build a partial inside the form with a list of already existing comments with
"Here is the comment text" (Click on this AJAX link to destroy it)...(More tricky...)

Call the add_comment(f, new_comment_text) function with reference to the f object to add a comment to the @post (existing but not saved - how to pass the reference to it via ajax ?). Ask this function to

```
@comment = @post.comments.build     
(or @comment = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(:comments).klass.new ??)
@comment.comment_text = new_comment_text
render a partial with @post.comments.all
```

**So is it possible to have
@post = Post.new() in function1
and access this object @post from function2 even if it is not saved yet in the DB ? function1 and function2 are in the same controller**

Any idea ???

Thk U :-)